# Sum of creation operators as one creation operator

Tags: tensor-products

Let $A = a^\dagger \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes a^\dagger$ act on $H \otimes H$ where $a^\dagger$ is the usual creation operator. I.e. we have

$a^\dagger |n \rangle = \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle \\
N |n \rangle = n |n \rangle$

where $N$ is the particle number operator.

Now, I would like to decompose the Hilbert space $H \otimes H$ as $R \otimes S$ such that $A$ acts as raising operator on $R$ and as zero or as identity on $S$ i.e. as $a^\dagger_R \otimes 0$ respectively $a^\dagger_R \otimes 1$. Is this possible and if so how?

Thanks for any advices :-)